# Kafka Topic has no leader, reelection fails

Tags: apache-kafka

I have the problem, that my kafka topics have no leader. Is there a solution that i can reelect a leader for all my topics?

```
CSVForOldSystem  PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: CSVForOldSystem  Partition: 0    Leader: none    Replicas: 1001  Isr: 1001
```

I Think i need a Leader or not? Broker has id 1006

I need to reelect a leader, but i don´t know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one broker, then your options include

1. Edit server.properties to explicitly set broker.id=1001. However, this will break any new existing topics that now have 1006 as the leader
2. you need to use `kafka-reassign-partitions` script to modify the broker id of that topic and all others to use 1006 instead of 1001. This may result in data loss if the data doesn't actually exist in that "new broker"

Comment: Thx, but there is no new topic that have 1006, all topics on my server have no leader. And that is the strange thing, but I will try to fix it like your suggestion. When it will not work, i will write here again :)

Comment: Are you running Kafka (and Zookeeper) in a container and did it restart? Did you not start kafka with persistent storage (not /tmp) and used an explicit broker id setting?

Comment: Hi, i have restartet the Docker Container, and It seems thet we don´t use fixed Broker ID settings. I got a new ID for the Broker after restart. Broker ID is now 1006 and Replica and ISR are on 1001. I have tried the soulution, but still not possible to elect a leader for my topics an partitions

Comment: Thanks to all, that had helped me. I got it running again. I had to delete all topics and restart zookeeper and kafka Docker container, so all is now with leader again

Comment: 1) I recommend you add the broker id to your container env-vars 2) Also mount a persistent volume. 3) Feel free to accept the answer using the checkmark next to the post